# How to setup a camera that follows a circle path?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create a camera that follows an object that rotates on a orbit around a sphere. But everytime the camera reaches the polar coordinates of the orbit, the direction changes. I just set the position of the camera according to the object that is has to follow and calling `lookAt` afterwards:

```
function render() {
    rotation += 0.002;

    // set the marker position
    pt = path.getPoint( t );

    // set the marker position
    marker.position.set( pt.x, pt.y, pt.z );
    marker.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0) );

    // rotate the mesh that illustrates the orbit
    mesh.rotation.y = rotation

    // set the camera position
    var cameraPt = cameraPath.getPoint( t );
    camera.position.set( cameraPt.x, cameraPt.y, cameraPt.z );
    camera.lookAt( marker.position );

    t = (t >= 1) ? 0 : t += 0.002;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Here's a complete fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/krw8nwLn/69/

I've created another fiddle with a second cube which represents the desired camera behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/krw8nwLn/70/

Comment: Your two links point to the same url

Comment: Oh, sorry! I‘ve updated the question :)

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the camera's `lookAt` function will always try to align the camera with the horizontal plane (so that the "up" direction is always (0, 1, 0). And when you reach the top and bottom of the ellipse path, the camera will instantaneously rotate 180° so that up is still up. You can also see this in your "desired behaviour" example, as the camera cube rotates so that the colors on the other side are shown.

A solution is to not use `lookAt` for this case, because it does not support cameras doing flips like this. Instead set the camera's `rotation` vector directly. (Which requires some math, but you look like a math guy.)

Comment: That would be too good to be true... :-) But thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I'm going to test some things!